# How much did all of the major battles in the MCU cost?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In every film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, there are multiple battles that I assume would cost millions of dollars in damage. I mean, in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, an entire city is destroyed. I assume that battles like these would cost millions if not billions of dollars (or pounds or euros or some other currency) in damages. All the private and public property damage, plus the medical bills of the wounded and the funeral bills of the dead, would cost a ridiculous amount of money.

Has someone crunched those numbers regarding all the damage caused by the heroes and villains of the MCU? I don't just mean the end battles, I mean *all* of the battles. Space battles excluded, of course, because I don't know if they can be properly measured..

Comment: Less than the cost of losing our freedom and lives!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, the numbers have not been crunched for *every* battle.

It would be absurd to think so, as there are so many factors that go into it and so much is unseen, that it would be about as accurate as pulling a random number between $1Bn and $1000Bn and going with that.

However, if we only take the Battle of New York, Washington DC, and Sokovia, we get around:

### $495.6Bn of damages and 274 casualties.

After a very quick google of the question's title, I was led to [this page](https://movieweb.com/avengers-captain-america-civilian-deaths-damages-costs/), which made a note of [a trailer for the 2016 *Captain America: Civil War*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxGYYfgHrBk), which showed infographics of the damage done in each of the places.

[image: Battle of New York: $18.8Bn damages, 74 casualties] [image: Washington DC: $2.8Bn damages, 23 casualties] [image: Sokovia: $474Bn damages, 177 casualties]

## Battles since Sokovia

As we all know, there have since been fights, including the airport fight in *Civil War*, Brawl in South Korea, Battle for Wakanda, *Infinity War*, etc. which would've caused more damage and possibly casualties. However, these are the only official values up to now, and anything else would be speculation.

---

Comment: Battle of Wakanda ended with a loss so vast that you can't put a price on it